# How to form regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String defined in Java as

`String str = "N3*<address.addressline1>~";`.

I want to find if there is any `'<'` and `'>'` in the string and if it is present, want to get the data between them. So, in this case output will be `address.addressline1`.

I was trying to do using `String.matches(regex)` to find if `<,>` pattern matches. But unable to form regex for the above.

I may have something like this also,

```
String str = "N4*<address.city>*<address.state>*<address.zipcode>~";
```

In this case, I need to find out all the strings `address.city, address.state, address.zipcode`. How can I do that?

Comment: well, what you are trying to do is not really regex recognition, it's getting a substring.
get two ints as index, indexof("<") and ">" and use these indices in a call to substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "N4*<address.city>*<address.state>*<address.zipcode>~";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:<)(.*?)(?:>)"); // ?: --> non-capturing group..
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
address.city
address.state
address.zipcode
```

Comment: I may have something like this also String str = "N4*<address.city>*<address.state>*<address.zipcode>~"; .. In that case, i need to get all the data. Above will only give me first one

Comment: Thanks a lot..can you please suggest me some good link so that i also can learn

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to capturing anything. The below code would get the strings which are enclosed within `<>`,

```
(?<=<)([^>]*)(?=>)
```

Your code would be,

```
    String s = "N4*<address.city>*<address.state>*<address.zipcode>~;";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=<)([^>]*)(?=>)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

**Output :**

```
address.city
address.state
address.zipcode
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/b9zIzl)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=<)` Lookbehind which tells the regex engine to set the matching marker just after to the `<` symbol.
- `([^>]*)(?=>)` Matches any character not of `>` zero or more times but it should be followed by `>`